# Atom snippet description with link

Tags: atom-editor

Is there a way to make a link inside a snippet description clickable/styled?
I know about `descriptionMoreURL` but I am interested in adding a second link.

This does not work:

```coffee
'.source.js':
    'test 1':
        'prefix' : 't1'
        'body': 't1()'
        'description': 'Also works in combination with https://link.com'
```

This does not work:

```coffee
'description': '[Also works in combination with](https://link.com)'
```

And this also does not work:

```coffee
'description': '<a href="https://link.com">Also works in combination with]</a>'
```

Does anyone know how to do it / is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible, unfortunately. The `description` doesn't seem to support any formatting whatsoever.

You can add HTML via [parameters `leftLabelHTML` and `rightLabelHTML`](https://github.com/atom/snippets#optional-parameters), but if you click the link, it inserts the snippet, which is not ideal.

For reference, here's the documentation for the underlying [`autocomplete-plus` suggestion parameters](https://github.com/atom/autocomplete-plus/wiki/Provider-API#suggestions).